# Add a project in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have `Visual Studio Ultimate` edition and need to add a project in TFS.

I want to make my local desktop as the `TFS server`.

> My desktop specs:
>   Windows 7
>   Visual Studio 2010 Utlimate

I have no idea how to go about it and add a new project in `TFS`. I read a lot of blogs but didn't find any that lists something from scratch.

As in when I try to create a Team project in TFS, i get the server section as empty. How to configure my local desktop to act as a `TFS server`??

Comment: Have you installed TFS yet, sounds like TFS express would suit your needs?

Comment: I didn't install TFS express. But i already see Team Foundation Server in Visual Studio Ultimate? Do i need to install anything else?

Comment: -1 no signs of research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx (Compatibility between Team Foundation clients and Team Foundation Server)

Second, you need to decide which version of TFS you are planning to run. Is your company paying for a version of it or are you planning on using the express edition available (2013)?

If your answer to that is TFS Express 2013, then I suggest you navigate to this link and download the installer. Run it and follow the instructions.

If you are planning a full licensed installation, you should familiarize yourself with the various components that come with it (Report server, Sharepoint, etc).

Here is a link to install and administration: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29035

Comment: maybe it will sound too naive....but what is the TFS that we get along with Visual Studion Install.

Comment: You don't get any with Visual Studio. all you get is the Team Explorer which is the client tool you would access TFS and its various facets. Can you explain what you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to start a .net project and want to add it in TFS for version control of source codes, etc.

Comment: And my company is not paying anything...i am ready to use express edition of TFS if available...i was using VSS earlier but i thot it will be a good idea to switch to TFS.

Comment: OK then just install 2013 Express as I said earlier and read the links so you have some idea of what you are doing. Keep in mind that VSS was source control while TFS is much more (source control as well as build system, work item management, etc). If you can upgrade to VS 2013 even better so you can get all the benefits offered by TFS 2013 Express.

Comment: ok....so what i will do is - First install TFS Express. Then configure my project there. And then in Visual Studio TFS(client) I will get the project configured in TFS express. Right? Anything i missed?

Comment: 1) Install TFS Express. 2) Create a Team Project (not to be confused with a Visual Studio code project). 3) Connect to the Team Project from Visual Studio and add your code project to it. There are lots of resources covering the details on this on the web.

Comment: One last thing....from my Visual Studio...when i do a 'Connect to Team Foundation Server'.....since the server will be my local system...what will be the URL or name of Team Foundation Server?

Comment: You'll enter the name of the your computer normally. So if your computer name is JOBOB, enter JOBOB and it should be able to figure it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

1.
If you haven't already, connect to your Visual Studio Online account and create your workspace folder.

2.Move the code you want to upload to the workspace folder.

3.Open your solution in Visual Studio.